# chunking same elements on list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have list of elements, for example:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,1]
```

and I want to get list of lists, and each sublist should contain equal elems, so in this example:

```
[[1,1,1],[2,2],[1]]
```

(In real case elems are objects, and I want to chunk/group them by equality based on chosen field)

I ended with such algorithm:

```
    val list = listOf(1,1,1,2,2,1)
    val groups = list
        .drop(1)
        .fold(mutableListOf(mutableListOf(list.first()))) { groups, next ->
            if (groups.last().last() == next) {
                groups.last().add(next)
            } else {
                groups.add(mutableListOf(next))
            }
            groups
        }
```

but is there a smarter way, fully functional, without mutable accumulator? Maybe there is some standard function I can use?

Comment: why do you have `.drop(1)`?

Comment: without this I would get [1,1,1,1] in first sub-list, try it. It could be written in different way, without `drop`, but now `if` inside fold lambda is very simple. I'm open for other ideas, but pls check them ;)

Comment: right, I see. You can use this as an alternative:
val groups = list.fold(mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()) { acc, elem ->
    if (acc.isEmpty() || acc.last().last() != elem) {
        acc.add(mutableListOf(elem))
    } else {
        acc.last().add(elem)
    }
    acc
}

Comment: I’m just curious because I see questions like this fairly often. Why do you want to find a pure functional solution to a problem that is a more clearly and elegantly solved with imperative code?

Comment: imo, this fold is elegant, maybe my need to have immutable accumulator is slight exaggeration,

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a better alternative than using *fold* for this.

You could rewrite your code along this:

```
val result: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = list
  .fold(mutableListOf()) { acc, item ->
    when (item) {
      acc.lastOrNull()?.first() -> acc.last().add(item)
      else                      -> acc.add(mutableListOf(item))
    }
    acc
  }
```

As you can see I did put the type specification on the 'receiving' variable, not on the start variable *mutableListOf()*, but that is just personal preferences. You could also put it in there or on the accumulator.

In addition I dropped – pun not intended – the specific case of the first element, and moved it into the *else* branch of the *when* clause.

Then, if you want to go immutable within the *fold* you could do this:

```
val result: List<List<Int>> = list
  .fold(listOf()) { acc, item ->
    when (item) {
      acc.lastOrNull()?.first() -> acc.dropLast(1) + listOf(acc.last() + listOf(item))
      else                      -> acc + listOf(listOf(item))
    }
  }
```

As you see the result is a list of lists, and this is also the case for each accumulator step. The drawback is, that it will be much, much slower. But personally I do not think that immutability in such a short piece of code is important.

---

Edit:

A completely different approach would be to gather the indices of where the changes from item to item happen, and then extract sublists:

```
val list = listOf(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)

val result = list
  .mapIndexedNotNull { index, value ->
    when {
      index == 0 || value != list[index - 1] -> index
      else                                   -> null
    }
  }
  .plus(list.size)
  .zipWithNext { from, to -> list.subList(from, to) }
```

Comment: yeah maybe this mutableList as accumulator is not so bad solution. I like your 1st sample, bu in real case I have objects not primitive types so `when` would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: As long as you have to check on equality of one property only, you can just add the property name to _item_ in _when_ and to _first()_, like this for a property called _name_: _when (item.name) {
      acc.lastOrNull()?.first()?.name -> acc.last().add(item)_

Comment: Yes, of course not such big problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to make this totally immutable (of course, `groupBy` is not relevant to your specifications), but you can consider an alternative implementation:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.consecutiveGroups(): Sequence<List<T>> = sequence {
    var group: MutableList<T>? = null
    for (item in this@consecutiveGroups) {
        if (group == null) {
            group = mutableListOf(item)
        } else if (group.last() == item) {
            group.add(item)
        } else {
            yield(group)
            group = mutableListOf(item)
        }
    }
    if (group != null) {
        yield(group)
    }
}
```

You could then call this like so:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
    val groups = list.consecutiveGroups().toList()
    println(groups) // Output: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [1]]
}
```